# Add HTML table data to $_post

Tags: javascript, php, html, dictionary

I wanted to add a Dictionary to PHP $_POST, Dictionary will be containing the data of the html table such that the columns heading are the keys and values(of respective key) are the list containing the table data(row wise) of their respective column.

**HTML** example

```html
<form action="/page.php" method="post">
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5642</td>
            <td>Paracetamol</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7849</td>
            <td>Crocin</td>
            <td>45.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6418</td>
            <td>Condom</td>
            <td>12.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4572</td>
            <td>Vitamin D</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I wanted to add this data to a dict(internal Structure of dictunary defined above) and this dictionary to $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the hidden fields for each row and items and then post it

```
<form action="/page.php" method="post">
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5642 <input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="5642"/></td>
            <td>Paracetamol <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="Paracetamol"/></td>
            <td>10.00 <input type="hidden" name="rate[]" value="10.00"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7849 <input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="7849"/></td>
            <td>Crocin <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="Crocin"/></td>
            <td>45.00<input type="hidden" name="rate[]" value="45:00"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6418 <input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="6418"/></td>
            <td>Condom <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="Condom"/></td>
            <td>12.00 <input type="hidden" name="rate[]" value="12:00"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4572</td>
            <td>Vitamin D <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="Vitamin D"/></td>
            <td>5.00 <input type="hidden" name="rate[]" value="5:00"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what `[ ]` this means in the name attribute

Comment: this indicates the element array for multiple elements like item_code.. if you write $_POST['item_code'], then value would be ['5642','7849','6418'] and so on for each records